# Overlay of flagging data with /timeline URL?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, flags

Perhaps I'm overseeing it but is there a way to see the flagging history of a question or answer mixed in within the /timeline URL?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/{questionid}/timeline
```

The general format for the `/timeline` URL is as above. I'd like to see when particular flags were applied to the question & answers as well. I did not see this data here when I was poking around.

I could go through my activity tab and find it that way or if I was lucky I could find it in one of the review queues (if I happened to flag through them), but often times I flag outside them, and so it's a pain to put this data together with the timeline of a given Q&A.

#### Why?

This answer on a question is what's driving me to ask this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/108576/timeline. I wanted to confirm when I flagged this. I believe that's my comment there, the timestamp seems to line up.

*timeline*

[image: ss #1]

*comment on answer*

[image: ss #2]

So it would be nice if the flagging data was mixed into the timeline view for easier corroboration.

Comment: I don't think this currently exists. Mods have a way to view the flag history of a post, and you can look at your own history to figure out when you flagged something, but there's no way to see your flag in the timeline view. In this case, that is when you flagged the post

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - what do you think the likelihood would be of getting something like this implemented if we were to ask? The only reason I know I flagged then is b/c I used the "auto comment" that you're seeing there above.

Comment: Well, you did ask by posting a feature-request. I have no idea how long it will take; I don't think the timeline view is a particularly high priority for them

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - OK bear with me, this is my 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an improvement, I think a better (short-term) solution would be to have the following two things implemented:

- notification that an answer you flagged has changed
- ability to retract a flag

This seems more easy to implement (but I am not the person having to do so), but more importantly, might reduce the work for the flag reviewers.

Comment: My suggestion was one of many potential improvements in performing reviewing/flagging. The notification one would be welcomed too. I'll often stumble upon replies days/weeks later where ppl neglected to reply correctly w/ an @ or spelled y name as sim instead of slm. Retracting would be helpful too.

Comment: That is a problem as well, but sometimes they do not reply at all. I would like to have the system notify me that the answer has changed, even if the poster of the Answer did not leave comment (but maybe reacted on the flag auto-message). I think the system already removes an auto-inserted message based on a flag once the flag is declined/disputed by the MODs, doesn't it?

Comment: The only way I've facilitated this myself is to star the Q's.

Comment: I did not know that also gave me answer-edit notifications.

Comment: I think it only gives me some deltas on the Q's however. Favorites in Stack Overflow are used to subscribe to notifications of a question's activity (edits and new answers). So it's only of limited use.